# Execução lenta de um problema de repetição for em c

Tags: c

Fiz este algoritmo para o problema abaixo. O mesmo funciona e retorna o valor desejado. Porém está com execução lenta para o tamanho do problema e a ferramenta,que corrige os problemas,não está aceitando o mesmo como certo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Problema:

> Escreva um programa para ler um valor inteiro N e que gere o quadrado de  cada um dos valores pares,
>   de 1 até N, inclusive N, se for o caso.
>
> Entrada
>
> A entrada conterá uma linha com um valor inteiro N, 5 < N < 2000.
>
> Saída
>
> A saída deve conter, uma linha para cada quadrado computado. Em cada l inha deve constar uma expressão
>   do tipo `xˆ2 = y`, onde `x` é um número par e `y` é o seu valor elevado ao quadrado. Imediatamente
>   após o valor de y deve aparecer o caractere de quebra de linha: `\n`.

Exemplo

```
Entrada
6
Saída
2ˆ2 = 4
4ˆ2 = 16
6ˆ2 = 36
```

Meu código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int main(){

    int n,i;

    scanf("%d",&n);
if((n%2)==0){
    for(i=2; i<=n; i = i+2){
            printf(" %d ^ 2 =  %d\n",i, i*i);
    }
}
else
    for(i=2; i<n; i = i+2){
            printf(" %d ^ 2 =  %d\n",i, i*i);
    }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Está muito confuso o que deve fazer e a questão do tempo. Dê mais detalhes, coloque de forma mais organizada pra ver se tem algum outro detalhe, porque não tem muito o que possa fazer para ficar mais rápido, pode dar um pequeno ganho, mas é ínfimo. Te deram uma resposta que até piora.

Comment: "execução lenta" - Quão lenta estamos a falar ? Qual o tempo que dá ? Qual o limite de tempo ? Qual a plataforma ?

Comment: pelo jeito é algum site de correção automática estilo URI, esses sites podem indicar timeout quando o programa demora muito pra dar o resultado. Esse "muito" indica que o programa possui uma complexidade (tipo O(n²)) maior que o necessário

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu algoritmo está fazendo comparações desnecessárias, tente dessa maneira:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    n/=2;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
         printf(" %d ^ 2 =  %d\n", 2*i, 4*i*i);

    return 0;
}
```